# Solve a set of non linear Equations on Galois Field

Tags: polynomials, algorithms, finite-fields, systems-of-equations

I have the following set of equations:

$$M_{1}=\frac{y_1-y_0}{x_1-x_0}$$

$$M_{2}=\frac{y_2-y_0}{x_2-x_0}$$

$M_1, M_2,  x_1, y_1, x_2, y_2,$ are known and they are chosen from a $GF(2^m).$ I want to find  $x_0,y_0$

I ll restate my question.
Someone chose three distinct x0,x1,x2, as well as y0,y1,y2, then computed M1, M2, and finally revealed M1,M2,x1,y1,x2,y2, but not x0,y0 to us.All the variables are chosen from a Galois Field.
I want to recover the unknown $x_0,y_0.$ Is it possible to accomplish that?

If a set of nonlinear equations have been constructed with the aforementioned procedure e.g.

$$M_1=\frac{k_1-(y_0+(\frac{y_1-y_0}{x_1-x_0})(l_1-x_0))}{(l_1-x_0)(l_1-x_1)}$$

$$M_2=\frac{k_2-(y_0+(\frac{y_1-y_0}{x_1-x_0})(l_2-x_0))}{(l_2-x_0)(l_2-x_1)}$$

$$M_3=\frac{k_3-(y_0+(\frac{y_1-y_0}{x_1-x_0})(l_3-x_0))}{(l_3-x_0)(l_3-x_1)}$$

$$M_4=\frac{k_4-(y_0+(\frac{y_1-y_0}{x_1-x_0})(l_4-x_0))}{(l_4-x_0)(l_4-x_1)}$$

where $x_0,y_0 x_1,y_1$ are the unknown GF elements.
 Can I recover the unknown elements?

My question was if the fact that the set of equations is defined on a Galois Field imposes any difficulties to find its solution.

If not I suppose that the set can be solved. Is this true?

Has mathematica or matlab any package that will help me to verify it?

When I tried to solve a system similar to the one above posted I found out that ${x_i}^{2}, 0\leq i \leq 2$ has come up. 
I think that I should have to compute the square root of the x0. 
Is it possible in GF?
 Is it also possible to compute the $\sqrt[1/n]{x_0}$?

Comment: For the first system: how would you solve it if they were numbers?

Comment: Sorry, I edited it.

Comment: In general solving polynomial system of equations over a finite field is NP-hard, so there is no general strategy. Nevertheless, maybe in your particular type of equations there is an easy way.

Comment: @Herc11 I don't think the original second system of the post can be rewritten in a linear form, unless you introduce new variables and wind up with more than four of them. [In that case the linear system doesn't have a unique sol'n.] Working on the given system I did get it down to solving quadratic equations. However for example $u^2+u+1=0$ has no solutions in $GF(8)$, as an exhaustive check shows, so that just because one cn extract squareroots is not enough to guarantee solutions to quadratics. [usual quad. formula involves div. by 2]

Comment: @coffeemath, my mistake. In my problem I know that set of equations has solution i.e. someone has constructed the equations. Then he reveals to me only $$k_i,l_i  M_i 1\leq i\leq 4$$. My question is can I then solve the system on GF with the provided info?A problem with the previous parameteres can be solved on R, but the sane stands for GF?

Comment: Moving punctuation inside the double-dollars. It looks silly otherwise :-)

Comment: @Jyrki Lahtonen Thanks:)

Comment: With the new approach, one is basically assuming that the solution exists in the Galois field in question. In one respect this means one could simply try all the possibilities until discovering the solution (a finite chore). But there is a way to solve the second system involving only solution of quadratic equations and rational operations. I'll add that to my answer if there is interest.

Comment: Note that you cannot simply try all the possibilities because the  GF can be large e.g. 2^128. The key point is to be able to solve the set, not to try different solutions. I think that even if the equations are 3 degree or more they can be solved.

Comment: @coffemath I think that the second problem is linear too.

Answer (score 2):

The first system can be solved in the usual way, provided the "slopes" $M_i$ are distinct. Solve each for the knowns $y_k$, $k=1,2$ and subtract. You can then get to
$$x_0=\frac{M_2x_2-M_1x_1-y_2+y_1}{M_2-M_1},$$
and then use one of the equations you already formed with this $x_0$ plugged in to get $y_0.$ Since this method only uses addition/subtraction multiplication/(nonzero)division it works in any field, in particular in your Galois field.

Comment: @Herc11 -- I'll look at that, but the first thing I'd suggest is to see if you can determine the "geometric meaning" of the set of the equations to be solved. In the first system it was easy to see it was two lines meeting at an unknown point, with slopes given, and given points one on each line. That made it clear how to solve, and also what to assume. For your second more complex system I wouldn't try it without geometric ideas.

Comment: It is easy to see the geometric meaning. It is the intersection points of 4 quadraticks (if it was defined over a GF). For each quadratick I know a point $$(k,l)$$ and the leading coefficient.
The unknowns are the intersection points of the 4 polynomials $$(x_0,y0),(x_1,y_1)$$

Comment: @Herc11 I think I see it. Will try to solve, but it looks a bit difficult.

Comment: If the equations were over $$R$$ it is too easy, the problem is about GFs. I am not usre if it can be solved over GFs.

Comment: @Herc11 If taking squareroots seems like the problem, or fourth roots, or other iterates of squareroots, note that every element of $GF(2^n)$ is a square, since $f(x)=x^2$ is then a field automorphism, injective since $x^2=y^2$ gives $y=\pm x$, and here $x=-x$.

Comment: @ Jyrki Lahtonen I dont know. What formula?"The solution/solvability of a univariate quadratic equation looks a bit different.
@coffemath Not only square roots. Because it may be needed to employ degree 3 polynomials...

In general, I do not know if there is any problem but see – Josué Tonelli-Cueto's Comment. Also, I tied to google it and the results were confusing. If I understand it cannot be sovled easily..I am confused.

Comment: For an example on what difficulties might be (if this is the case I am talking about) see this https://openaccess.leidenuniv.nl/bitstream/handle/1887/4392/Thesis.pdf?sequence=1

Comment: @coffeemath As you said I think that the computation of $$x^{1/n}$$ when n is odd it is impossible. Or it isnt?

Comment: @Herc11 The expression $(y_1-y_0)/(x_1-x_0)$ in all four equations may be replaced by a single new variable $m$, since once $x_0,x_1,y_0$ are found, and $m$ is found, one can solve and get $y_1$ from that. [this is because $y_1$ appears only in that slope term] Then the equations really seem to be quadratic in the variables $x_0,x_1,y_0,m$, making it somewhat likely one only needs square or fourth roots to solve. I don't know if one can extract cuberoots at random in $GF(2^n)$ but I suspect not.

Comment: @Herc11: If $n$ is coprime to $L=2^{138}-1$, then you can find (generalized Euclid's algorithm) a modular inverse of $n$ modulo $L$, i.e. a number $m$ such that $nm\equiv1\pmod L$. Then $x^{1/n}=x^m$ for all $x\in GF(2^{138})$. This you can efficiently calculate with repeated squaring (assuming you are using a normal basis representation or something like that internally).

Comment: Cuberoots are a problem, because $3\mid 2^{138}-1$. They exist only for one third of the elements. And Herc, sorry about not realizing that it is not a quadratic. It was about points of intersection of four quadratics. Thinking...

Comment: @Jyrki Lahtonen. Therefore, if I want to define the intersection point of degree-3 polynomials, "as cuberoots are a problem" the set of the polynomials might not be solved.The equations are derived by Newton Interpolation. $$

a_k=\frac{P(x_k)-\sum_{i=0}^{k-1} a_i\prod_{j=0}^{i-1}(x_k-x_j)}{\prod_{j=0}^{k-1}(x_k-x_j)}$$  Thats why as coffeemath said $$\frac{y_1-y_0}{x_1-x_0}$$ can be replaced by m.Essentially $$\frac{y_1-y_0}{x_1-x_0}=a_0$$

Comment: @coffeemath. I think you follow the same procedure as in the question,based on your remark. But I think that not even square roots are needed.$$a_3=\frac{y_3-(a_0+a_1(x_3-x_0)+a_2(x_3-x_0)(x_3-x_1))}{(x_3-x_0)(x_3-x_1)(x_3-x_2)}$$ 
In the above equation we can substitute the differences $$(x_3-x_0)$$ with a variable. So, the system will be linear. Am i wrong?>

Answer (score 0):

I think tha the second system can be solved lik the first one. More specifically,
The second system can be solved too. If it is setted $\frac{y_1-y_0}{x_1-x_0}=a_1$ and $a_0=y_0$ the system of equations can be rewritten as
$$M_1=\frac{k_1-(a_0+a_1(l_1-x_0))} {(l_1-x_0)(l_1-x_1)}$$
$$M_2=\frac{k_2-(a_0+a_1(l_2-x_0))} {(l_2-x_0)(l_2-x_1)}$$
$$M_3=\frac{k_3-(a_0+a_1(l_3-x_0))} {(l_3-x_0)(l_3-x_1)}$$
$$M_4=\frac{k_4-(a_0+a_1(l_4-x_0))} {(l_4-x_0)(l_4-x_1)}$$

where $M_1, M_2, M_3,M_4, k_1,l_1,k_2,l_2,k_3,l_3,k_3,k_4$ are known.
Then the 4 unknowns are the $x_0,x_1, a_0, a_1$.
The system of equations is linear, and if there is a solution, the system can be solved.
Afterwards, by   
$$\frac{y_1-y_0}{x_1-x_0}=a_1$$   $$a_0=y_0$$
 the  $y_0, y_1$ can be recovered. True or FAlse????